EV3 Color Sensors Disconnecting
My EV3 color sensors disconnect a fair number of times. What can I do to prevent this from happening apart from changing the sensors and cables?

What are you doing or what is happening when the sensor disconnects? Both the possible causes and the symptoms could be telling, so please describe such a scenario in as much detail as you can.

Just following using PD algorithm until a third sensor sees a certain color, but the problem is with sensors that are following the line. They sometimes just disconnect in the middle of the line following. I hope that helps describing the scenario.

It does help a little, at least we now know that the sensor is built in a model, which itself is moving. This means an intermittent contact issue in the cable is not excluded yet, so I'd suggest setting up the model in a way that eliminates all movements and check if the sensor still disconnects even in the absence of movement.
